# How to display the data returned from an async function in .ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ejs

I am passing an object containing async functions to the .ejs file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const functions = require('./functions.js')

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000', new Date())
})
 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard.ejs', { functions })
})
```

the function console logs the data and also returns it

```
const getPrice = async (coin) => {
    let data = await CoinGeckoClient.coins.fetch(coin);
    console.log(coin, "GBP", data.data.market_data.current_price.gbp)
    console.log(data.data.market_data.price_change_percentage_24h, '% / 24 hours')
    return `
    ${coin} "GBP" ${data.data.market_data.current_price.gbp}
    ${data.data.market_data.price_change_percentage_24h}% / 24 hours')
    `
};
```

I want to render the returned data in the .ejs file.  Im trying this

```
<body>
    <p>
        <%= functions.getPrice('ethereum') %>
    </p>
</body>
```

the console log is successful when I refresh the browser

```
ethereum GBP 3141.5
3.00725 % / 24 hours
```

so the function is being called, but the data is not rendered to the screen.

I instead get [object Promise].

I feel like this is an async issue but not sure how/if I can get the ejs to await the returning data.  Am I structuring this wrongly?

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Configure EJS with `async: true` and then use `await functions.getPrice(...)` in your template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ejs async true with node Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203249/ejs-async-true-with-node-express)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your function in your JS file then pass the result to the EJS file:

```
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard.ejs', { price: await functions.getPrice('ethereum')})
})
```

Then in your EJS:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <%= price %>
    </p>
</body>
```