# Is there a way to make async functions return a value inside ejs?

Tags: ejs

I'm using template like this

```
<%= (async ()=>{return "some test here";})() %>
```

after rendering, I'm getting Object Promise, but I need just a value. Example of rendering

```js
let result = ejs.render('<%= (async ()=>{return "some test here";})() %>');
console.log("result = "+result);
let neededResult = ejs.render('<%= (()=>{return "some test here";})() %>');
console.log("neededResult = "+neededResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ejs@3.1.6/ejs.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to convert promise to a value in ejs template?

Comment: you should `await` outside before passing it to your template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60203249/2864740 , see async=true option (https://ejs.co/); in turn, will need to `await` the render result or otherwise hand-off as promise

Comment: Thanks, can I reconfigure htmlWebpackPlugin or ejs-loader to render ejs asynchronously