# why axios returns [object Promise] instead of data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios, ejs

I have a function that returns a value from an API. However, when I use the function within an EJS template, it returns a promise rather than the data.
When I console.log (data), it shows the actual data I'm looking for.

**Helper**

```
const axios = require("axios");

    const getBrokerName = async (id) => {
        API_BROKERS_URL = `${process.env.API_URL}/api/v1/brokers/?`;

        const params = new URLSearchParams({
            id:id,
            key: process.env.API_KEY,
        });
        
        try {
            const {data} = await axios.get(`${API_BROKERS_URL}${params}`);
            console.log(data.name)
            return data.name
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

module.exports = { getBrokerName }
```

**EJS file**

```
<%= helper.getBrokerName(account.broker_id) %>
```

**Result**

```
[object Promise]
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38884522) | [Async function returning promise, instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51338277) | [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516390) | [What are asynchronous functions in JavaScript? What is "async" and "await" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62196932)

Comment: Could you please reformat my function with the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling an async function in EJS. Async functions always return a promise.

For that to work with EJS, you need to set the async parameter when calling the res.render function in your API.

Look at this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60824780/7025986

TL;DR

In your server API:

```js
const ejs = require('ejs');
const html = await ejs.renderFile(view, data, /* >> */ {async: true} /* << */ );
res.send(html);
```

and in your .ejs file:

```js
<%- await helper.getBrokerName(account.broker_id) ->
```