# Html tag in ejs then block doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, ejs

I need to call fetch function and show the response as html.
But when I call it and try to show it in then block, html tag doesn't work while console.log works.

```
<p>page</p>

<% myFetchInterfaceFunction().then( res =>{ %> 
    <p>response</p>
    <% console.log('response') %>
<% }) %>
```

result

browser:

`page`

console:

`response`

Why this happens and how to show async function's returned value as html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ejs async true with node Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203249/ejs-async-true-with-node-express)

Comment: Alternately, await all async data fetching **before** calling `res.render()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a better way, to display content in browser:-

**Idea:-**

1. In res.render({}), which is inside async-await function, send parameter to ejs that you want to display in browser.
2. In ejs, this tag ( <%= > ) helps you to access the value sent by calling file. Now you can display in browser.

->In calling file, i.e js:- (handle async-await in this function)

return res.render("name-of-ejs-file", {parameters-you-want-to-send});

->In ejs file, you can access like this

<%=  %>

**Logic Explaination:-**
e.g:- If I want to show user email in browser, then I will do this:-

1. In calling file, send user as parameter
   ->e.g return res.render("ejsfile", {user});
2. In ejs file, format to show it to browser:-
   ->

   <%= locals.user.email %>

   (inside paragraph tag)

This displays user email in browser.
I hope this answers your question, Thank You.

Regards:-

**Rakshath U Shetty**